# Java Tomcat Application is Saving Timestamp to the Database in Wrong Timezone

Tags: java, mysql, linux, tomcat, timezone

In a Java Tomcat application, I am using `-Duser.timezone=Canada/Central`. Also, I setup server timezone to `Canada/Central`. However, when I save timestamp to the database, using `LocalDateTime.now()`, the UTC timestamp is being saved to the database.

Anyone has idea what's going wrong?

- OS: Amazon Linux
- Database: Mysql 8 in AWS RDS

Thanks.

Comment: Is the SQL column type TIMESTAMP? According to the MySQL docs "MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. [...]  As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store."

Comment: Yes, the column type is TIMESTAMP

Comment: As an aside the time zone ID `Canada/Central` is deprecated. You should use `America/Winnipeg` instead. See for example [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: @Sadat - Can you post the code where you insert into the table, and read the value from the table

Comment: I basically want to store timestamp to the database in my configured timezone not UTC.  The code involve several modules, I will try to post a summarized version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, I found an elegant solution.

In jdbc connection string, adding the following parameters:

```
useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=America/Winnipeg
```